# Emacs 26.3: Weird frame title issue with KDE

Tags: frames

I recently switched to CentOS 7.7, KDE 4.x, and Emacs 26.3. Previously, I was using GNOME and a much older version of Emacs. Before, whenever I opened Emacs, the titlebar of a lone Emacs window was `emacs@hostname`. Now, it's `emacs@hostname <@hostname>`, which seems less than desirable. I can't figure out if the issue is with Emacs or KDE. Any ideas as to what is wrong here and what I can do to get it back to `emacs@hostname`?

Answer (score 0):

Emacs controls its frametitle via variable `frame-title-format`.
So you could change the value of that variable temporarily, to get an idea weather or not KDE is manipulating it somehow.

I.e. do `M-: (setq frame-title-format "foobar")` `return` and check the new title of the frame.

If the frametitle is now `foobar <@hostname>`, then KDE changes it and you have to look into KDE settings or KDE applets, plugins or whatever to modify the behavior.

If it is now just `foobar`, then it is controlled entirely by emacs. Have a read at [EmacsWiki: Frame Title](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FrameTitle) to see what options you can use to change it to what you like.

Comment: Yes, I read that wiki page. My frame-title-format is unchanged from the default. I will give your suggestion a try on Monday.

Comment: Setq-ing `frame-title-format` does not change the title of an existing frame. If I `C-x 5 2` to create a new frame, the new frame has the title `foobar <@hostname> <2>` and the old frame now has the title `foobar <@hostname>`. So I think you are right that the issue is with KDE really, but I still don't know how to change it or even where to ask, honestly. AskUbuntu and tag it with "kde"?

Comment: @EdSabol yeah probably you should ask there. It might be interesting which UI flavor of Emacs do you use: gtk3 or lucid (plain x11)? I can't help with KDE nor Gnome.

Comment: I use lucid (plain X11).